# WAS 8.5 runtime jars are not shown in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jar

I'm using WAS 8.5 in eclipse kepler for our JSF 2.0 project and our project is based on Maven. Somehow WAS is picking the older J2EE jar and its not taking the J2EE jar from its lib folder. When I expand the WAS in the build path, it's not showing any runtime jar. How can I make the eclipse to show all WAS runtime jars in the build path? 
Web Project -> Configure build path -> Libraries -> WAS 8.5 (Expand it) "No Jars are shown here"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiaLI.jpg

Comment: Was is not going to take `J2EE` from your lib. That the while backbone of it and why are you try to do this any way. If you must read up on `Shared Resouces` that might be the only way if that.

Comment: Shahzeb, thanks for responding. When I have WAS 7, i'm able to see all the WAS 7 runtime jars in the eclipse but it is not happening with WAS 8

Comment: Any chance of posting a screen shot of what you had in WAS7. You were probably using IBM JDK and not you are not. As for the WAS runtimes you can not see them in eclipse.

Comment: Its not allowing me to post the screen shot :( Is there any other way to post the screen shot?

Comment: If you edit the question you will see the button to upload in the action bar that appears.

Comment: Its a screen shot of WAS 8

Comment: For your project to see those jars, you either add them as provided dependencies in the project's maven pom file (recommended way since you have it) or you set the WAS 8.5 runtime as your project's target runtime.

Comment: WAS 8.5 is the runtime for my project but still no luck

Comment: Then try adding them as provided dependencies in your pom.

Comment: @DSF Sorry for the delay. If I make it as provided, then I'm getting build errors.

Comment: You also need to load them into your local maven repository if they are not available in a remote one.